# First intersection of each line in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How can I select/extract the first intersection of each line?

[image]

Comment: How do you define "first"?

Comment: That's the problem. Tool "line Intersections"  doesn't number the points in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) QGIS tool, set the line layer as **Input layer**, set the **Output geometry type** parameter to **Point**, set the following expression in the **Geometry expression** parameter, remember to set the layer name of the intersecting layer.

```
aggregate(
    'Intersecting layer name / id', -- set inside quotes the layer name / id of the intersecting layer
    'array_agg',
    point_n(
        array_filter(
            geometries_to_array(difference(
                geometry(@parent),
                $geometry
            )),
            touches(@element, point_n(geometry(@parent), 1))
        )[0],
        -1
    ),
    intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry),
    order_by:=length(array_filter(
        geometries_to_array(difference(
            geometry(@parent),
            $geometry
        )),
        touches(@element, point_n(geometry(@parent), 1))
    )[0])
)[0]
```

Then just run the algorithm, this works intersecting with lines and polygons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Intersect the line layers using [Line Intersections](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgislineintersections). Output is a point layer of all line intersections.
2. Create a virtual layer:

You need a unique identifier in your line layer, mine is called `id`. Modify the fourth line and change `line.id` to whatever your id column is called, like `line.youridcolumn`.

And change lines 6 and 7 to match the names of your layers.

The query will join the intersection points to the closest line, then measure its distance along the line, and select the point with the shortest distance along the line for each unique line:

```sql
SELECT lineid, min(distalong) as distalong, pointgeom AS geometry
FROM
(
SELECT line.id AS lineid, line.geometry AS linegeom, pnt.geometry AS pointgeom,
    Line_Locate_Point(line.geometry, pnt.geometry) AS distalong
from linelayer AS line
join intersections AS pnt
on PtDistWithin(line.geometry, pnt.geometry, 1)
) sub
GROUP BY lineid
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(
    'polygon_layer_name',
    'array_agg',
    point_n(
            intersection(
                geometry(@parent),
                $geometry),1
            )
)[0]
```

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer. If you have anything new to add, you can mention with details. Kindly add context of your solution.